# bootstrap nav alignment issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So i have a website im building with bootstrap 4 and having a few issues. Need help if anyone can help me. The site is at www.castawayministries.com/newsite/. Every thing i do that i have found online doesn't work

1. I have multiple dropdows in main nav and noticed the  tag for each has an id="navbarDropdown" which you can only have one id of the same name on each html page. Does it matter if i add like navbarDropdownAbout to one and so on for each one having a different id for each one? dropdowns seem to work fine so far.
2. Trying to get the nav to go to the far right while logo is on left but "justify-content-end", "ml-auto", "mr-auto", none of those are doing anything and im not sure why.
3. Other than that i would love for anyone to check it out and let me know what i did wrong or should change or whatever.

Have tried "justify-content-end", "ml-auto", "mr-auto"

Navigation should be aligned right

Comment: Please share the relevant code that replicates your issue on your question with a code snippet, don't send people to other sites

Comment: Now, I did check your code, remove the `.row` div in which you put the `nav` in, then add `ml-auto` class to the `ul` tag, you can also remove the `justify-content-end` class

Comment: But im not only wanting help with just the nav code but also to look at my site and see how it looks and works and get feedback.

Comment: Still, your question is about the navbar, you should show the code you have for that particular issue so people can take a look at it, and make changes to it to make it work. Opinions on how your site looks can be varied, so maybe this is not the best place for that. This should be a good read: [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @mjohnson24 Please read **[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** The code to repro the issue *must* be posted in the question itself. Questions should be helpful to future readers which doesn't happen when you link to an external site. Don't ask multiple questions at once.

Comment: ok.. ill try to work on that the next time i post

Comment: @IvanS95 ok awesome! That worked like a charm. So what did removing the .row like you mentioned change that allowed ml-auto to work? before it didn't work with that code on the `ul` tag. And whats the difference between `justify-content-end` and `ml-auto`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, this is the code you have on the page (should be on your question)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.jpg" width="129" height="85" alt="Castaway Ministries Logo"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
       </button>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           About
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Mission</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Vision</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Staff</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           Requirements
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Privileges</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Rules and Regulations</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           Gallery
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2013</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2016</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Now, your issue can be fixed in two ways, you have the `.navbar` inside a `.row`, which is a Flex container in Bootstrap, `rows`, per [Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#how-it-works), should only have `columns` as direct children:

> In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and only columns may be immediate children of rows.

Which the `navbar` is not, this makes the row not use the full width of the screen and only fits its content, so when you set `justify-content-end` you don't see changes because the container (the row) is already at its full width, so there's no space left to arrange items.

To solve this you can either remove the `row` containing the `navbar` and just leave the navbar, or add a `col` class to the navbar without removing the `row` div containing it, so it behaves as it should.

I'd **recommend removing** the row, as its really not necessary and adds negative margins that you might not want.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="">
  <!-- Remove the row -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.jpg" width="129" height="85" alt="Castaway Ministries Logo"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
           </button>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto"> <!-- Add ml-auto to align right -->
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
               About
              </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Mission</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Vision</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Staff</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
               Requirements
              </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Privileges</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Rules and Regulations</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
               Gallery
              </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2013</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2016</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <nav class="col navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <!-- Add a col class -->
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.jpg" width="129" height="85" alt="Castaway Ministries Logo"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
           </button>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto"> <!-- Add ml-auto to align right -->
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
               About
              </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Mission</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Vision</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Staff</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
               Requirements
              </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Privileges</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Rules and Regulations</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
               Gallery
              </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2013</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2016</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh ok... Now i get it. Your explanation helped clear that up alot. This is my first time using bootstrap and coding it on my own so trying to learn by actually coding it on my own and getting help when needed. Thanks for the explanation and the help on the fix.

Comment: @mjohnson24 no prom; the official documentation is extremely good, give it a read and you shouldn't have many issues. And again, try to structure your question better lol, the links provided in the question's comments are helpful :) Oh and if this helped you remember to mark it as accepted

Comment: yea this is only the second time using stackoverflow so trying to get use to the strict structure and all that is used and how to ask them.